# mysql_data_seek versus storing data in array

Tags: php, mysql

I have searched for a few hours already but have found nothing on the subject.

I am developing a website that depends on a query to define the elements that must be loaded on the page. But to organize the data, I must repass the result of this query 4 times.

At first try, I started using mysql_data_seek so I could repass the query, but I started losing performance. Due to this, I tried exchanging the mysql_data_seek for putting the data in an array and running a foreach loop.

The performance didn't improve in any way I could measure, so I started wondering which is, in fact, the best option. Building a rather big data array ou executing multiple times the mysql_fetch_array.

My application is currently running with PHP 5.2.17, MySQL, and everything is in a localhost. Unfortunatly, I have a busy database, but never have had any problems with the number of connections to it.

Is there some preferable way to execute this task? Is there any other option besides mysql_data_seek or the big array data? Has anyone some information regarding benchmarking testes of these options?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I don't know the exact implementation of mysql library, but I believe that when you run a query which returns a result it stores the entire result in the equivalent of an array.  If that's the case, there's really no performance gain from storing it in an array yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your problem may lie in indexing appropriate fields in your database, most databases also [cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html) frequently served queries but they do tend to discard them once the table they go over is altered. (which makes sense)

So you could trust in your database to do what it does well: query for and retrieve data and help it by making sure there's little contention on the table and/or placing appropriate [indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimization-indexes.html). This in turn can however alter the performance of writes which may not be unimportant in your case, only you really can judge that. (indexes have to be calculated and kept).

The PHP extension you use will play a part as well, if speed is of the essence: 'upgrade' to [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and do a ->[fetch_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)(), since it will cut down on communication between php process and the database server. The only reason against this would be if the amount of data you query is so enormous that it halts or bogs down your php/webserver processes or even your whole server by forcing it into swap.

The table type you use can be of importance, certain types of queries seem to run faster on MYISAM as opposed to INNODB. If you want to retool a bit then you could store this data (or a copy of it) in mysql's [HEAP engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html), so just in memory. You'd need to be careful to synchronize it with a disktable on writes though if you want to keep altered data for sure. (just in case of a server failure or shutdown)

Alternatively you could cache your data in something like [memcache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) or by using [apc_store](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php), which should be very fast since it's in php process memory. The big caveat here is that [APC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) generally has less memory available for storage though.(default being [32MB](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php)) Memcache's big adavantage is that while still fast, it's distributed, so if you have multiple servers running they could share this data.

You could try a nosql database, preferably one that's just a key-store, not even a document store, such as [redis](http://redis.io/).

And finally you could hardcode your values in your php script, make sure to still use something like [eaccelerator](https://eaccelerator.net/) or APC and verify wether you really need to use them 4 times or wether you can't just cache the output of whatever it is you actually create with it.

So I'm sorry I can't give you a ready-made answer but performance questions, when applicable, usually require a multi-pronged approach. :-|

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
I would like to compile the queries into php scripts, like you mentioned, but, unfortunatly, I would need a lot of time to make it work as neatly and dynamic as it is now.
I will, definetly look into some of the points you made.
I am so much grateful. Thank you.